# GROUP BY without aggregate function in SparkSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to reproduce in SparkSQL the same behavior than the group by in sql.

Here is an example of what I am able to do in SQL and not in SparkSQL with SparkSQL functions:

Input dataset:

```scala
val input = Seq(
  ("Warsaw", 2016, 2),
  ("Toronto", 2016, 4),
  ("Toronto", 2017, 1),
  ("Toronto", 2017, 1)).toDF("city", "year", "count")
```

Which results in:

```scala
+-------+----+-----+
|city   |year|count|
+-------+----+-----+
|Warsaw |2016|2    |
|Toronto|2016|4    |
|Toronto|2017|1    |
|Toronto|2017|1    |
+-------+----+-----+
```

Then I register the table as a temporary one using:

```scala
input.createOrReplaceTempView("input")
```

Then by using sql

```
select city, year, count 
from result 
group by 1,2,3
```

Which gives

```scala
+-------+----+-----+
|city   |year|count|
+-------+----+-----+
|Warsaw |2016|2    |
|Toronto|2016|4    |
|Toronto|2017|1    |
+-------+----+-----+
```

I would like to the same with SparkSQL native functions, and if possible NOT USE dropDuplicates.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Window` function - `row_number()`.

```
val columns = input.columns.map(col(_))

input.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(columns: _*).orderBy(columns: _*)))
  .where("rn = 1")
  .drop("rn")
  .show()
```

Comment: Thanks! In terms of performance, is there any consideration to take ?

Comment: I have tried it on a big dataset, and unfortunately dropDuplicates gives a faster result. Do you think that it's possible to improve it (even if I think that it's very improved)

Comment: You can try with caching dataframe after reading the data.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why you are avoiding dropDuplicates when it's giving faster results compare to Window function.

Comment: because it doesn't give the same result as groupBy. And also because I am migrating from SQL to SpqrkSQL and the inital queries contain groupBy